# Balanced - Set card as default funding source

Tags: payment, balanced-payments

I have a buyer account with several, valid cards associated with it. According to [Balanced's](https://www.balancedpayments.com/) [documentation](https://www.balancedpayments.com/docs/python#resources.Credit) the most recently added card is the default funding source. How do I set another, existing card as the default funding source without asking the user to resubmit their card details to create a new card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot currently set an alternate funding source, the most recently added card is always the default. To debit or credit a specific funding instrument such as a card or bank account you must pass through the URI of the object as the parameter `funding_source` or `funding_destination` respectively:

```
buyer = balanced.Account.find(uri_of_account)
card = buyer.cards[x]
debit = buyer.debit(amount_in_cents, source_uri=card.uri)

merchant = balanced.Account.find(uri_of_account)
bank_account = merchant.bank_accounts[0]
credit = merchant.credit(amount_in_cents, destination_uri=bank_account.uri)
```

Comment: Very nice, but where to get uri_of_account value and not understand cards[x]. can u plz exp this.

Comment: When i am using debit = buyer.debit(amount_in_cents, source_uri=card.uri) got error: incorrect-uri: Could not find field [hold_uri]. Can you suggest me?

Comment: harsh4u - can you create a new question for this with an example script? someone will help if you can create a full example.

Comment: marshall - Thanks to you, i got solutions using small changes. New code: debit = buyer.debit(amount_in_cents, :source_uri=>card.uri) solved.